# Valid vs Validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to learn jQuery and have stumbled across a strange problem (perhaps strange only to me). So here goes:
I have a form with id `mainform` in my app. Now I wanted to validate the form with jQuery. Also I wanted to set the invalid fields in blue color. For that I added css

```
.error{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

When I run `$('form#mainform').valid();` in the console, I get the highlights and everything works fine. However when I run `$('form#mainform').validate();`, I get lots of data and nothing happens.

Also if I run `.valid()` before `validate()`, various options such as error placement etc. don't seem to work.

I want to know the difference between these, why they are behaving so differently and where they should be used. I will appreciate if anyone can point me in right direction.

Note: I am using jquery.validate.js

Comment: have you ever looked in the docu? [valid()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) vs [validate()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) !? assuming you are yousing the validaton plugin, if not, which one do you use?

Comment: It may be a good idea to link to the library you are using. Afaik, this is not a core-method.

Comment: Yes please. link your library your are using to validate form.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are several differences between valid and validate.  Interestingly, although the docs state that

> "validate needs to be called on the form before checking it using this
>   method"

this isn't actually the case, as valid calls validate() anyway.

The two major differences are

1. If you want to pass options into the plugin, you must call validate({...})
2. validate() doesn't highlight any errors, whereas valid() does. You could say that valid performs 'eager' validation whereas validate sets up a 'lazy' validation, basically if you call validate() you won't see any immediate change on the page, whereas with valid() you might.
3. valid can be called on a subset of form elements, whereas validate must be called on the form itself:

   $('form').validate({/* options here */});

   $('.myfields').valid()

Comment: Thanks for the info. I scoured through the docs and couldn't get anything much better. My point is, what's the use of `validate()` anyway?

Comment: it sets up lazy validation - call it on document ready.  Have a play with these examples http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/

Comment: "as valid calls validate() anyway" That's backwards according to the docs: http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/

Comment: docs are a bit confusing - check the source https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/core.js#L102

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Jquery validate library.

[Docs saying](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/)

> validate() needs to be called on the form before checking it using valid() method.

Not  .`valid`() before `validate`()

http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/

http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate