# jQuery valid return true when the form is NOT valid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, model-view-controller, form-submit

I have an MVC razor view with the validation rules for the properties defined in my model.
Since i want to return a partialView to my page i did a "custom" submit function to be called :

```
function SubmitNewstock() {
    var form = $("form");
    form.validate();
    alert("Valid: " + form.valid());
}
```

This is what i get:

[image]

FIRST i get the alert where it says that the .valid() is true.
SECOND i get that the validation errors in the page.

I also tried: 
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");

View:

```
@model EstudioVenta.Stock
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Codigo_, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-5 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-7">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Codigo_, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Codigo del Articulo" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Codigo_)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nombre_, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-5 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-7">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nombre_, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Nombre de Articulo" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nombre_)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cantidad, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-5 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-7">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Cantidad, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Catidad de Articulos" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cantidad)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PrecioCosto_, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-5 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-7">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PrecioCosto_, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Precio de Costo del Articulo" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PrecioCosto_)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PrecioVenta_, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-5 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-7">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PrecioVenta_, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Precio de Venta del Articulo" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PrecioVenta_)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Agregar Stock" class="btn btn-default btn-primary btn-block" onclick="SubmitNewstock()" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FechaDeEntrada_)
}
....

<script>
    function SubmitNewstock() {
        var form = $("form");
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
        form.validate();
        alert("Valid: " + form.valid());
    }

    $(function () {
        //Save the browser time in a hidden
        $("#FechaDeEntrada_").val(GetClienTime());
        setInterval(function () {
            $("#FechaDeEntrada_").val(GetClienTime());
        }, 10000); //Do it again every 10 sec

        //DATATABLES
        var table = $('#stockTable').DataTable({
            "pageLength": 25,
            language: {
                search: "Buscar:",
                decimal: ",",
                paginate: {
                    first: "Primera",
                    previous: "Anterior",
                    next: "Siguiente",
                    last: "Ultima"
                },
            }
        });
    });
</script>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Why i'm getting the .valid() as true if the page is NOT valid for the submit?

Comment: see if it's a placeholder problem... like get rid of the placeholders first.

Comment: I cannot duplicate this at all - the alert is `false` (assuming you have validation attributes on your properties). And you do not need `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse()` - thats is only necessary if your dynamically loading the form controls

Comment: @sksallaj Nop, did not work.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I do have the validation attributes, i.e.: <input id="Codigo_" class="form-control input-validation-error" type="text" value="" name="Codigo_" data-val-required="El articulo debe tener un codigo" data-val="true">

Comment: Then there must be other code you have not shown us causing the issue. I suggest you comment out everything except the form and the `SubmitNewstock()` script to test (although its unclear what the point of that script is if you have client side validation enabled)

Comment: here's something intesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404188/valid-vs-validate validate must be called on the form itself (which is what you're doing.. but valid must be called on the actual fields on the form to work.

Comment: @sksallaj, That's not correct (calling `.valid()` on a `<form>` element checks all form controls within the form). The key word in the link is _valid **can** be called on a subset of form elements_

Comment: @StephenMuecke I jsut opened up top 20 posts on mvc and I am here to see only your comments on all. Good going brother

Comment: @StephenMuecke as you can see here, i have comented all: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Aux46pBnK0vlFFHDtND6__aLfg7WTTDt7cCQKqcPIEk/edit?usp=sharing ,and the .valid() keeps returning true

Comment: I'm wondering if it has something to do with razor and when the lifecycle of the html component gets mounted onto the DOM.. interfering with jquery's valid(). What happens if you replace Html.BeginForm with <form> ?

Comment: @sksallaj No man, tried that and is not working...

Comment: @sksallaj even this is giving true...

Answer (score 0):

please check how many forms do you have on page.

assign id to your form then try

var form = $("#myform");