# Validating form using jQuery Form Validator on ajax post ()

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am using form validator [plugin](http://www.formvalidator.net/) to validate my forms.

It is working properly if I am not submitting data using jQuery post method.
On using jQuery post it is not validating the form on submit.

My code is

```
<form action="UpdatedProfile" method="post" name="updateprofile" id="UpdatedProfile" class="form-horizontal">
<div class=" form-group ">
          <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label>First Name</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">
              <input type="text" name="fname" cssClass="form-control" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="First Name is required"/>
        </div>
    </div>
   </form>

<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.validate();
                $(document).on('click', '#submit', function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    console.log($('#UpdatedBasicProfile').serialize());
                    $.post("Updated", $('#UpdatedProfile').serialize(), function (data)
                   {....});
          });
         });
  </script>
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: I think you confused with validate() and valid(). [Valid vs Validate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404188/valid-vs-validate)

Answer (score 0):

put a submit button in the form and define validation rule in js like

```
$('#frm_registration').validate({
    rules:
    {
        fname: required
    },
    messages:
    {
        fname : 'Please enter name'
    }
});
```

or if the button is of type button then initiate validation on its click like:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#frm_registration').valid();     // will initiate the validation
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If the validator is working when clicked on submit button, you could trigger a click event on the button rather then listening the document for any clicks and if the target is the given button.